# Laravel 5.4 Script loading issue

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm working on my first Laravel project (5.4), actually I don't understand why my js script doesn't work like I expected.
I use Mix and Blade :

```
// webpack.mix.js
let { mix } = require('laravel-mix').mix;

    // copy fonts and patterns
mix .copy('resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/fonts', 'public/fonts')
    .copy('resources/assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
    .copy('resources/assets/patterns', 'public/css/patterns')

    // compile scss and concatenate css files
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles([
        'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css',
        'resources/assets/vendor/animate/animate.css'
        // ...
    ], 'public/css/vendor.css')

    // concatenate js files
    .js([
        'resources/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
        'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
        'resources/assets/js/app.js'
        // ...
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
    .options({ processCssUrls: false }); // fix for path issue : https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/issues/1360
```

After `npm run dev` compliation looks good :

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 6497ms                                                     4:20:57 PM

                                   Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf   45.4 kB          [emitted]         
                              /js/app.js    1.2 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
                       mix-manifest.json  66 bytes          [emitted]         
  fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot   20.1 kB          [emitted]         
fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2     18 kB          [emitted]         
  fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg    109 kB          [emitted]         
 fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff   23.4 kB          [emitted]         
                            /css/app.css    178 kB       0  [emitted]         /js/app
           fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf    166 kB          [emitted]         
           fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg    444 kB          [emitted]  [big]  
           fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot    166 kB          [emitted]         
          fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff     98 kB          [emitted]         
         fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2   77.2 kB          [emitted]         
                   fonts/FontAwesome.otf    135 kB          [emitted]         
         css/patterns/header-profile.png   5.88 kB          [emitted]
```

CSS works fine, bootstrap.js also works and when I check inside `/js/app.js` it seems like everything is inside.

An here is my tempate :

```
{{-- app.blade.php--}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale', 'en') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/vendor.css') !!}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/app.css') !!}" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main view  -->
    @yield('content')

    <script src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @section('scripts')
    @show
</body>
</html>
```

My troubles began when I want to add a script inside the script section from a child.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('test');
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` like if jquery wasn't loaded.

I have no clue why, any idea ?

**[note]**
It works if I replace inside *app.blade.php* :

```
<script src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For fun, if you replace `$` with `jQuery` (so you'd have `jQuery(document).ready(function () {`), does it work? Also, if you open your browser's dev tools, is app.js loading successfully?

Comment: Same error with `jQuery`.
As far I can see `app.js` is loaded, that why I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figure who was guilty : Mix (or the way I used Mix)

I wrongly believed that `mix.js` and `mix.scripts` was the same function. But `mix.scripts` only combine and minify files while `mix.js` also do compiling ECMAScript 2015 and module bundling. I don't really know why but it was a problem in my case.

```
mix.js(['public/js/admin.js',
    'public/js/dashboard.js'], 'public/js');
```

replaced by :

```
mix.scripts(['public/js/admin.js',
    'public/js/dashboard.js'], 'public/js/all.js');
```

See more : [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#working-with-scripts)

Comment: You need to specify a destination filename option for mix.scripts, such as 'public/js/all.js' just specifying a directory results in a EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory error.

Comment: Sorry I meant for the mix.scripts one only, the mix.js one is fine as a folder

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and the problem was that at the moment I was using jQuery for the first time, the `app.js` file generated by webpack wasn't loaded yet.

You can do a simple test to see if you have the same issue. In your first chunk of code where you use jQuery (the line of code that throws you the $ error), wrap that code in this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
 // Your jQuery code
});
```

One workaround is to load `app.js` earlier in your blade main layout file, but I am sure it can be done in a better way. I am fairly new to Laravel, so I am still figuring out these kinds of things...

**Edit:**

Ok, I think I understood now how to do it properly:

1. In your main blade layout (in my case `app.blade.php`), at the bottom right before the `</body>` tag, load your webpack script, all other external scripts you might load, and finally add a yield scripts section.

Example:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="other/scripts/that/you/need.js"></script>
@yield('scripts')
```

2. In the blade template where you need jQuery code, instead of adding it directly in the content section, you create a new section called *scripts*.

Example:

```
@section('content')
//Your view code
@endsection

@section('scripts')
//Your jQuery code
@endsection
```

That way, your jQuery code is loaded after the main layout has already loaded the webpack javascript file (which loads jQuery).

Comment: Nice try, but it doesn't work, `document.addEventListener` doesn't solve the issue.  
And the html structure that you suggest is the one I currently use.

Comment: This just saved me hours of frustration. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include js file as shown below in your blade files as in my case I'm including add-section.js which is placed inside public/js

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/add-section.js') }}"></script>
@yield('scripts')
```