# Laravel 8 Summernote Jquery Errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to hook up summernote wysiwyg with Laravel 8, no matter what I do I am getting a constant jquery error. I have tried to use webpack for the scripts and added scripts directly to the page. The order to my scripts should be correct and I am executing the code after the scripts However, the error is a basic error and I can't nail down the issue.

The webpack file is default and I have run npm run dev & prod.

The code listed put into a basic HTML file runs with no errors, there must be something I am doing with Laravel.

```
jquery.js:4055 Uncaught TypeError: "#summernote".summernote is not a function
```

App.blade.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>
 


    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

//rest of the template is out of the box Laravel base install with auth installed

   <form method="post">
            <textarea id="summernote" name="editordata"></textarea>
          </form>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" src="{{asset('js/main.js')}}" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
/* $('#summernote').summernote({
    placeholder: 'Hello Bootstrap 4',
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 100 */
// Code still produces the error here 
});

});
$('#summernote').summernote({
    placeholder: 'Hello Bootstrap 4',
    tabsize: 2,
    height: 100
});
// Code still produces the error here
```

Happy to provide more information, help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Summernote can be picky about the jQuery version. Perhaps try the version mentioned in their install notes `3.4.1`? https://github.com/summernote/summernote

Comment: I didn't get any errors. while setting up this

Comment: I have tried 3.4.1 and still get the error. I can get summernote note running in flat html with the above version of jquery. Laravel must be adding something to the mix.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with these

**Before the end of `</thead>`**

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

**Inside `<form>`**

```
<div id="summernote"></div>
```

**Before the end of `</body>`**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote();
  });
</script>
```

---

[Jsfiddle Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/m9xea7yn/)

[image: Preview]

---

**Useful links**

1. [Summernote Getting started](https://summernote.org/getting-started/)
2. [Summernote Examples](https://summernote.org/examples/)

---

> **Issue might be Summernote get loaded before the JQuery library**

Comment: Thank you for responding.I am using the codebase directly from the Summernote site. The does run outside of Laravel perfectly. But when I add the components to Laravel I get the js error. I do agree that there must be an issue with the order the scripts load, but I dont know what is going wrong.

Comment: add your main js on the footer and the rest of your JS on the header. I've worked with Summernote and I never get this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I cant take credit. An older slightly related Laravel issue had a solution:

[Laravel 5.4 Script loading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126944/laravel-5-4-script-loading-issue/43149982)

The contributor is @jordan

By isolating the script into a @section and adding $yield('scripts') below the js files solved the problem. Still not sure what Laravel is doing to the scripts as the page loads, but I have a solution. Thanks for all of your help those who contributed, I always value the input and suggestions.